# Unity- vs code error: if ($?) { dotnet run $Player_Movement }

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, error-handling, unity-container

Hi I am getting "cd "c:\Users\UMUT\Desktop\Unity Projects\Newest\Assets" ; if
($?) { dotnet run $Player_Movement }" message and I get this error message  "Couldn't find a project to run. Ensure a project exists in C:\Users\UMUT\Desktop\Unity Projects\Newest\Assets, or pass the path to the project using --project." in my Vs code Unity project. İn my another old project I have a C# script named Player_Movement but I am getting this error in my new Unity Project when I try to debug the project.I downloaded C# extension.I downl Any solutions or reason why it is happening?

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class New : MonoBehaviour 
{
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
 Debug.Log("hi");   
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    
}
}
```

Comment: You asked this yesterday.

Comment: I changed question and added new error message

Comment: First, ensure that VSCode and the plugin Debugger for Unity are installed successfully. 1. When everything is installed successfully and you find that clicking Run-Unity Debugger does not respond, first check whether there is launch.jason in this path, and delete it if there is. 2. After deleting, click here to create a launch.jason and then click Unity Debugger

Comment: @Housheng-MSFT Thanks but I solved this issue with resetting Vs code settings and changing C# extension version to 24.4

Comment: Hi a python learner, glad to know you've found the solution to resolve this issue! Please consider accepting it as an answer to change its status to Answered. 
It will also help others to solve a similar issue. See [can I answer my own question..](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), Just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reseted Vs code settings to default and my problem is fixed.